# Why in algebraic geometry we suppose that our field is perfect??

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Im new to algebraic geometry and Im reading the book : "Algebraic geometry in coding theory and cryptography" of Harald Niederreiter and Chaoping Xing.

My question is : why do we ask of our field to be perfect?

I know that this is equivalent to saying that all irreducible polynomials have
distinct roots.

Comment: It is a convenient simplifying assumption. It's more typical to assume the field is algebraically closed but I suppose for the purposes of coding theory and cryptography you need to work with finite fields instead...

Comment: Most fields are perfect anyway : The fields with characteristic $0$ and the finite fields. Cryprography usually works with finite structures , so the fields used for cryptography are usually perfect.

Comment: @DonnieDarko - let $k$ be the finite field with $p>0$ elements and let $K:=k(t)$ be the function field in one independent variable $t$. The polynomial $f(T):=T^p-t \in K[T]$ is irreducible but in $\overline{K}[T]$ there is a polynomial $T-\alpha$ with $(T-\alpha)^p=f(T)$. Hence if you consider function fields in characteristic $p>0$ you will end up with inseparable extensions.

Comment: As an example: If you are studying elliptic curves you will end up studying function fields in one (and several) variables, hence you will end up studying inseparable extensions.

Comment: There is one point: in char $p$, perfect $\mathbb F_p$-algebras are good, not only perfect fields. For example, you could consult section 3.1 of [AWS notes by Morrow](https://www.math.arizona.edu/~swc/aws/2019/2019MorrowNotes.pdf).